# Why does a SELECT statement dirty cache buffers in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, cache, explain

I am running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` in my Postgres 9.3 server. I end up seeing something like `Buffers: shared hit=166416 dirtied=2` in the output.
[From the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html#AEN75034), "dirtied" indicates:

> The number of blocks dirtied indicates the number of previously
>   unmodified blocks that were changed by this query; while the number of
>   blocks written indicates the number of previously-dirtied blocks
>   evicted from cache by this backend during query processing.

This sounds to me like the process of marking a block dirty should only happen when updating data though.  My query is a `SELECT`, however, and only reads data. I would imagine it would only report hits or reads. I am obviously mistaken.  What exactly is happening in this situation, though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has a simple reason.

In PostgreSQL a row has to go through a visibility check. On the first read, the system checks if a row can be seen by everybody. If it is, it will be "frozen". This is where the writes come from. Similarly, `VACUUM` also sets bits.

There is a detailed explanation: http://www.cybertec.at/speeding-up-things-with-hint-bits/.

Comment: Your blog is a source of really valuable information.  At the same time, please add the main points of your post there to this answer, so that it complies with the rules here.

Comment: the thing is: in postgresql a row has to go through a visibility check. on first read the system checks if a row can be seen by everybody. if it is, it will be "frozen". this is where the writes come from. btw, vacuum also sets bits. it is a similar issue.

Comment: I have a complaint. You certainly meant "hint bits" here. "Frozen" is something quite different in PostgreSQL, and tuples are never frozen during a `SELECT`.