# Eliminate duplicates and optimize performance for big count and small LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a big query in my Postgres 9.1 database:

```
SELECT *,
       count(*) OVER () AS full_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(message.messagetime,message.messageid) message.messagetime,
         message.messageid,
         message.clientid,
         message.message_type,
         message.contenturl,
         message.nativecontenturl,
         message.receiverid,
         message.status,
         message.nativeisa,
         message.nativegs,
         message.isa,
         message.gs,
         message.originalfilename,
         message.duplicatekeyfield,
         message.duplicatenativeid,
         extractkeyfield.keyfield,
         sender.description AS sendername,
         receiver.description AS receivername
  FROM message
    LEFT JOIN extractkeyfield ON message.messageid = extractkeyfield.messageid
    LEFT JOIN clientprofile sender ON message.clientid = sender.clientid
    LEFT JOIN clientprofile receiver ON message.receiverid = receiver.clientid
  WHERE message.messagetime BETWEEN '01-01-2015   03:40:50'::timestamp AND '04-01-2016   03:35:09'::timestamp
) message
ORDER BY message.messagetime DESC limit 100 offset 0
```

Locally my query does not take too long but when I am connected to the server it can take up to 2 minutes to return the data. I'm not sure if it's because too much data is being transferred or a bad/unoptimized query. I am using all of the information returned from the query. My query is returns 1,249,333 rows.

I have tried to create an index and tried answers from multiple posts but nothing seemed to improve or help:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (one column)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98995/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-one-column)

Any tips or help to decrease my query time would be much appreciated!

#### `EXPLAIN` output

See: http://explain.depesz.com/s/ui1

```
 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1748742.62..1748742.87 rows=100 width=350) (actual time=129247.099..129247.385 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1748742.62..1751833.33 rows=1236283 width=350) (actual time=129247.094..129247.195 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: public.message.messagetime
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 76kB
         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1660621.55..1701492.77 rows=1236283 width=350) (actual time=121565.119..126665.924 rows=1249333 loops=1)
               ->  Unique  (cost=1660621.55..1673676.41 rows=1236283 width=350) (actual time=109482.221..117931.767 rows=1249333 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=1660621.55..1664973.17 rows=1740647 width=350) (actual time=109482.216..113785.356 rows=2397272 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: public.message.messagetime, public.message.messageid
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 866352kB
                           ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=201396.04..361691.11 rows=1740647 width=350) (actual time=12600.048..30933.450 rows=2397272 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: ((extractkeyfield.messageid)::text = (public.message.messageid)::text)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on extractkeyfield  (cost=0.00..47477.74 rows=1765974 width=45) (actual time=0.023..4422.157 rows=1765974 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=130405.50..130405.50 rows=1236283 width=343) (actual time=12584.450..12584.450 rows=1249333 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 992kB
                                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=200.65..130405.50 rows=1236283 width=343) (actual time=3.609..8758.093 rows=1249333 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: (public.message.receiverid = receiver.clientid)
                                             ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=100.33..113306.28 rows=1236283 width=325) (actual time=1.874..5929.557 rows=1249333 loops=1)
                                                   Hash Cond: (public.message.clientid = sender.clientid)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on message  (cost=0.00..96207.07 rows=1236283 width=307) (actual time=0.051..2623.433 rows=1249333 loops=1)
                                                         Filter: ((messagetime >= '2015-01-01 03:40:50'::timestamp without time zone) AND (messagetime <= '2016-04-01 03:35:09'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=90.70..90.70 rows=770 width=26) (actual time=1.809..1.809 rows=770 loops=1)
                                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 47kB
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on clientprofile sender  (cost=0.00..90.70 rows=770 width=26) (actual time=0.004..0.913 rows=770 loops=1)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=90.70..90.70 rows=770 width=26) (actual time=1.723..1.723 rows=770 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 47kB
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on clientprofile receiver  (cost=0.00..90.70 rows=770 width=26) (actual time=0.003..0.842 rows=770 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 129462.319 ms
```

#### Table definitions

Table `message`

```
      Column       |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 messageid         | character varying(255)   | not null  | extended |
 clientid          | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 parentid          | character varying(100)   |           | extended |
 receiptid         | character varying(100)   |           | extended |
 message_type      | character varying(50)    |           | extended |
 billable          | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 contenturl        | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 messagetime       | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |
 originalfilename  | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 receiverid        | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 originalclientid  | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 status            | character varying(100)   |           | extended |
 nativemessageid   | character varying(100)   |           | extended |
 nativecontenturl  | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 refmessageid      | character varying(100)   |           | extended |
 msgtotcount       | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 msgindex          | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 messagesize       | bigint                   |           | plain    |
 isconsolidated    | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 refisa            | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 refgs             | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 refst             | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 isa               | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 gs                | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 st                | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 nativeisa         | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 nativegs          | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 nativest          | character varying(15)    |           | extended |
 last_modified     | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |
 ricbatchid        | character varying(25)    |           | extended |
 reconciled        | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 duplicatekeyfield | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 duplicatenativeid | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 msgmode           | character varying(25)    |           | extended |
 isnotrans         | boolean                  |           | plain    |
 parentmsgid       | character varying(256)   |           | extended |
 originatingserver | character varying(8)     |           | extended |
 statusdetail      | character varying(100)   |           | extended |

Indexes:
    "message_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (messageid)
    "message_clientid_receiverid" btree (clientid, receiverid)
    "message_clientid_receiverid_status_messagetype" btree (clientid, receiverid, status, message_type)
    "message_gs" btree (gs)
    "message_isa" btree (isa)
    "message_last_modified" btree (last_modified)
    "message_messagetime_clientid_receiverid_status_messagetype" btree (messagetime, clientid, receiverid, status, message_type)
    "message_nativecontenturl" btree (nativecontenturl)
    "message_nativegs" btree (nativegs)
    "message_nativeisa" btree (nativeisa)
    "message_nativemessageid" btree (nativemessageid)
    "message_nativest" btree (nativest)
    "message_receiverid" btree (receiverid)
    "message_refgs" btree (refgs)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "message_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "message_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "msgstatus" FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES msgstatuslist(msgstatus)
Has OIDs: no
```

Table `clientprofile`

```
                  Column                  |           Type           |       Modifiers        | Storage  | Description
------------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------
 clientid                                 | bigint                   | not null               | plain    |
 description                              | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 role                                     | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 filetype                                 | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 erroremail                               | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 messageenvelope                          | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 preprequired                             | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 preprocessordocument                     | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 transporttype                            | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 transporturl                             | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 notransactiontype                        | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 usageindicator                           | character(1)             |                        | extended |
 requiresreceiptaggregation               | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 requirestransactionaggregation           | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 requiresvalidation                       | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 last_modified                            | timestamp with time zone |                        | plain    |
 clientemail                              | character varying(500)   |                        | extended |
 numberofhours                            | bigint                   |                        | plain    |
 wantnotification                         | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 requiresserverasgnctrlnums               | boolean                  | default false          | plain    |
 destextractor                            | character varying(256)   |                        | extended |
 notranslationpreprocessor                | character varying(255)   |                        | extended |
 alsoincrementserverctrlnumbersonresubmit | boolean                  | not null default false | plain    |
 includeoriginaltransactioninformation    | boolean                  |                        | plain    |
 credithold                               | boolean                  | not null default false | plain    |
 creditholdreason                         | text                     |                        | extended |
Indexes:
    "clientprofile_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (clientid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "activecustomermap" CONSTRAINT "activecustomermap_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "aggmappingid" CONSTRAINT "aggmappingid_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "controlnumbers" CONSTRAINT "controlnumbers_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "controlnumbers" CONSTRAINT "controlnumbers_senderid" FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "customerinfo" CONSTRAINT "customerinfo_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "customermap" CONSTRAINT "customermap_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "documentinfo" CONSTRAINT "documentinfo_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "documentinfo" CONSTRAINT "documentinfo_tpid" FOREIGN KEY (tpid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "message" CONSTRAINT "message_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "message" CONSTRAINT "message_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "notransextractor" CONSTRAINT "notransextractor_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "notransextractor" CONSTRAINT "notransextractor_senderid" FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "notransinfo" CONSTRAINT "notransinfo_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "notransinfo" CONSTRAINT "notransinfo_senderid" FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "senderisamap" CONSTRAINT "senderisamap_parentid" FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "senderisamap" CONSTRAINT "senderisamap_senderid" FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "tptxnhelper" CONSTRAINT "tptxnhelper_receiverid" FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "tptxnhelper" CONSTRAINT "tptxnhelper_senderid" FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "translationmapping" CONSTRAINT "translationmapping_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "translationmapping" CONSTRAINT "translationmapping_tpid" FOREIGN KEY (tpid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "validation" CONSTRAINT "validation_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "xmcuser" CONSTRAINT "xmcuser_clientid" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES clientprofile(clientid) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    customerinfo_client_add AFTER INSERT ON clientprofile FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_customerinfo_clientid()
```

Table `extractkeyfield`

```
    Column     |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 primaryid     | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 keyfieldtype  | character varying(23)    |           | extended |
 keyfield      | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 messageid     | character varying(255)   |           | extended |
 keyfieldtime  | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |
 last_modified | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |
Indexes:
    "extractkeyfield_keyfield" btree (keyfield)
    "extractkeyfield_last_modified" btree (last_modified)
    "extractkeyfield_messageid" btree (messageid)
    "extractkeyfield_primaryid" btree (primaryid)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: You have one sort step that is done on disk: "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 113984kB*" try increasing `work_mem` for that session until this is done in memory. Btw: according to the plan, your query only takes 1.6 **seconds**, not 2 minutes

Comment: Okay I will try increasing the work_mem but this analyze was taken locally, the 2 minutes I mentioned was the time it took my web app to finish loading all the data from the server

Comment: Then you should take the plan from the server that is slow. Not from a computer where you don't have the problem

Comment: Also: "*query is returning 1,249,333 results*" can't be true or you posted the wrong query. Because the query you posted only returns 100 rows due to `limit 100`. And yes: transferring 1.2 million rows and _displaying_ it on the client _can_ take 2 minutes. This is all just second guessing if you don't show us the **real** query and the **real** execution plan.

Comment: The query is the real query, the execution plan should be the same since the setup and database is the same?!... I might have used the wrong term for 'results', it is limited to 100 rows but it counts ALL results then limits the first 100 to show. The 1,249,333 is the total number of results that fit the query but it's paginated for every 100 results

Comment: Then the query isn't your problem, because that runs in 1.6 seconds, not 2 minutes. You need to check other places if you need to tune that.

Comment: We need the actual output from your actual problem query showing actual numbers. And we need cardinalities, index and table definitions and some other things. Please follow instructions in the [tag-info to \[postgresql-performance\]](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: Obviously, there can be multiple related rows in `extractkeyfield`, but you only return one `keyfield`. Currently you using an *arbitrary* pick. Do you care which one is picked? Do you want them all - in an array field maybe? Or do you want a deterministic pick? Please clarify: Postgres 9.1 or 9.5? You have both versions in your question. Depending on your *actual* version there are various ways to make this much faster yet.

Comment: No I do not care which one is picked, and just one. Postgres 9.1 ( i do plan to update to 9.5 if that would help increase its speed )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Query

Your question updates revealed that your query can be improved radically:

```
SELECT m.*
     , (SELECT keyfield  -- correlated subquery
        FROM   extractkeyfield 
        WHERE  messageid = m.messageid
        LIMIT  1)    AS keyfield
     , s.description AS sendername
     , r.description AS receivername
FROM  (
   SELECT messagetime    -- no DISTINCT necessary
        , messageid
        , clientid
        , message_type
        , contenturl
        , nativecontenturl
        , receiverid
        , status
        , nativeisa
        , nativegs
        , isa
        , gs
        , originalfilename
        , duplicatekeyfield
        , duplicatenativeid
        , count(*) OVER () AS full_count
   FROM   message
   WHERE  messagetime >= timestamp '2015-01-01 03:40:50'  -- incl. lower bound
   AND    messagetime <  timestamp '2016-04-01 03:35:10'  -- excl. upper bound
   ORDER  BY messagetime DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  100            -- count and limit before joining more tables
   ) m
LEFT   JOIN clientprofile s ON s.clientid = m.clientid  -- join later
LEFT   JOIN clientprofile r ON r.clientid = m.receiverid;
```

#### Indexes

The perfect **indexes** for this query would be:

```
CREATE INDEX message_messagetime_idx ON message (messagetime DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Usefulness depends on the percentage of rows selected. (You still did not provide cardinalities.) For a small percentage, the index is more likely to be useful.

Your existing index `message_messagetime_clientid_receiverid_status_messagetype` works as well, less efficiently since it carries some more columns of "dead freight" for the use case.

Joins to `clientprofile` are covered by its PK. To optimize read performance you might create a multicolumn index on `(clientid, description)` to allow index-only scans. Since the rows are wide, this should pay.

Finally, `extractkeyfield` could profit from another multicolumn index on  `(messageid, keyfield)`. Again, only useful if you get index-only scans out of it. The rows are not as wide, the benefit is smaller than for `clientprofile`.

If you get all of this right, the query should be faster by orders of magnitude.

#### Major points

You still get an arbitrary pick from multiple related `extractkeyfield.keyfield`. That's according to your definition. Typically, a deterministic pick is more useful.

- Since `messageid` is the PK of table `message`
  <strike>`DISTINCT ON (message.messagetime, message.messageid)`</strike> *never* makes sense. `DISTINCT ON (message.messageid)` would achieve the same, cheaper. Since you need the total count before `LIMIT`, a `DISTINCT` step makes the query *much* more expensive since *all* involved rows have to processed (not just counted). Luckily, `DISTINCT` can be avoided completely.
- The correlated subquery with `LIMIT 1` prevents duplicates a priori. So you don't need the expensive `DISTINCT ON` for the big table.

  ```
  (SELECT keyfield
   FROM   extractkeyfield 
   WHERE  messageid = m.messageid
   LIMIT  1)
  ```

  In Postgres 9.3+ you can also use a `LATERAL` join. Detailed explanation:

  - [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- Select, count and limit rows from your main table *before* you join to additional tables. That's what happens in my subquery `m`. Else you do a lot of additional work just to throw it away later.
- You shouldn't need more `work_mem` with the fixed query. That was a side effect of the needless `DISTINCT` step for > 1M rows. Check for lines mentioning "Disk" in connection with "sort" in the `EXPLAIN` output of the new query.
- I modified your predicate for the time range:

  ```
  WHERE  messagetime >= timestamp '2015-01-01 03:40:50'  -- incl. lower bound
  AND    messagetime <  timestamp '2016-04-01 03:35:10'  -- excl. upper bound
  ```

  Consider the explanation:

  - [PostgreSQL splitting time range into days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457463/939860)
- Your column `messagetime` can be NULL. Careful with descending sort order! I made that:

  ```
  ORDER  BY messagetime DESC NULLS LAST
  ```

  Details:

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Aside: your table definitions can probably be improved. Among other things, `varchar(255)` is an unlikely candidate for a PK. And I suspect some of your many indexes might not be used. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Your query is about 4 times faster!! I am getting duplicate results from query and it returned 195 rows (I'm guessing the extra 95 are duplicates)

Comment: @KyleBradley: Consider the update.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly and gives me a ton of insight in improving sql performance!!!!...unfortunately I forgot to add an important part to my question -_-      I forgot to mention that I am adding more parameters to the query dynamically. This is only a problem when I try to add (AND keyfield = '1002')  to the where clause

Comment: Because your solution filters by message table where keyfield is in extractkeyfield table, i could use 2 different queries if I had to, but was curious if it is possible to incorporate this easily into the answer you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

@Erwin's response is on the money (there was an error regarding the placement of `DISTINCT ON` but it is fixed now). This variant assumes that message.messageid is a primary key (or unique):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(m.messageid) m.*,
         extractkeyfield.keyfield,
         sender.description AS sendername,
         receiver.description AS receivername
FROM (
  SELECT
  FROM (
    SELECT messagetime,
           messageid,
           clientid,
           message_type,
           contenturl,
           nativecontenturl,
           receiverid,
           status,
           nativeisa,
           nativegs,
           isa,
           gs,
           originalfilename,
           duplicatekeyfield,
           duplicatenativeid,
           count(*) OVER () AS full_count
    FROM message
    WHERE message.messagetime BETWEEN '01-01-2015   03:40:50'::timestamp AND '04-01-2016   03:35:09'::timestamp
    ) x
  ORDER BY messagetime DESC
  LIMIT 100
  ) m
LEFT JOIN extractkeyfield ON m.messageid = extractkeyfield.messageid
LEFT JOIN clientprofile sender ON m.clientid = sender.clientid
LEFT JOIN clientprofile receiver ON m.receiverid = receiver.clientid
```

Comment: I get an error with your query, syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Comment: But there is an error in DISTINCT ON because I am getting duplicate results

Comment: There was an extra `SELECT *` at the beginning, it's fixed now.
I'm puzzled about you getting duplicate results, is `message.messageid` a primary key?