# Optimizing slow performance of simple SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, performance, upgrade, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I have an app called 'Links' where 1) users congregate in groups and add others, 2) post content for each other in the said groups. Groups are defined by a `links_group` table in my postgresql 9.6.5 DB, whereas the replies they post in these are defined by a `links_reply` table. Overall the DB's performance is great.

However one `SELECT` query on the `links_reply` table is consistently showing up in slow_log. It's taking longer than 500ms, and is ~10X slower than what I'm experiencing in most other postgresql operations.

I used the Django ORM to generate the query. Here's the ORM call: `replies = Reply.objects.select_related('writer__userprofile').filter(which_group=group).order_by('-submitted_on')[:25]`. Essentially, this is selecting the latest 25 replies for a given group object. It's also selecting associated `user` and `userprofile` objects as well.

Here's an example of the corresponding SQL from my slow log: **LOG:  duration: 8476.309 ms  statement:**

```
SELECT

    "links_reply"."id",             "links_reply"."text", 
    "links_reply"."which_group_id", "links_reply"."writer_id",
    "links_reply"."submitted_on",   "links_reply"."image",
    "links_reply"."device",         "links_reply"."category", 

    "auth_user"."id",               "auth_user"."username", 

    "links_userprofile"."id",       "links_userprofile"."user_id",
    "links_userprofile"."score",    "links_userprofile"."avatar" 

FROM 

    "links_reply" 
    INNER JOIN "auth_user" 
        ON ("links_reply"."writer_id" = "auth_user"."id") 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "links_userprofile" 
        ON ("auth_user"."id" = "links_userprofile"."user_id") 
WHERE "links_reply"."which_group_id" = 124479 
ORDER BY "links_reply"."submitted_on" DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Look at the the explain analyze results here: **https://explain.depesz.com/s/G4X** The index scan (backward) seems to be eating up all the time.

Here's the output of `\d links_reply`:

```
Table "public.links_reply"
     Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         
----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_reply_id_seq'::regclass)
 text           | text                     | not null
 which_group_id | integer                  | not null
 writer_id      | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 image          | character varying(100)   | 
 category       | character varying(15)    | not null
 device         | character varying(10)    | default '1'::character varying
Indexes:
    "links_reply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "category_index" btree (category)
    "links_reply_submitted_on" btree (submitted_on)
    "links_reply_which_group_id" btree (which_group_id)
    "links_reply_writer_id" btree (writer_id)
    "text_index" btree (text)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_reply_which_group_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_group_id) REFERENCES links_group(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_reply_writer_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (writer_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_groupseen" CONSTRAINT "links_groupseen_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_reply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_report" CONSTRAINT "links_report_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_reply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

It's a big table (~25M rows).  The hardware it's operating on has 16 cores and 60 GB memory. It shares this machine with a python app. But I've been monitoring the server's performance and I don't see bottlenecks there.

Is there any way I can improve this query's performance? Please advise on all options (if any) I have here.

---

Note that this query performed *exceptionally well till last week*. What's changed since then? I carried out a `pg_dump` and then `pg_restore` of the DB (on a separate VM), and I upgraded from Postgresql 9.3.10 to 9.6.5. I also used a connection pooler called `pgbouncer` before, which I haven't configured on the new VM I've migrated to yet.  That's it.

Lastly, I've also noticed (from user experience) that for all group objects created till last week, the query still performs fast. But all new objects being created now are producing slow log. Could this be some kind of an indexing issue, specifically with the `links_reply_submitted_on` index?

---

**Update:** The prescribed optimizations really turned things around. Have a look:

[image]

Comment: Please don't change the nature of the question *after* answers have been given. The changed `ORDER BY` is a major change.

Comment: @erwinbrandstetter: Yea I unforunately updated while you were writing this great response. But you know, even using order by `id` does NOT change the situation in terms of performance at all. I made this change yesterday, it's precisely as bad (if not worse). I can revert it in the question though, if you want me to. Should I? Also removed extraneous fields (and made that actual change my my query as well - ofcourse, to no avail).

Comment: Yes, please. To be consistent. The answer should help you either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Suspected main issues (synopsis)

1. You need to run `ANALYZE` after a major version upgrade with `pg_upgrade`. Table statistics are not copied. Possibly tune autovacuum settings, too.
2. A multicolumn index on `(which_group_id, submitted_on DESC)` should serve this query *much* better.

#### Query

Formatted query without noise and with table aliases for better readability:

```
SELECT lr.id, lr.text, lr.which_group_id, lr.writer_id
     , lr.submitted_on, lr.image, lr.device, lr.category
     , au.id, au.username
     , lu.id, lu.user_id, lu.score, lu.avatar
FROM   links_reply            lr
JOIN   auth_user              au ON au.id = lr.writer_id
LEFT   JOIN links_userprofile lu ON lu.user_id = au.id
WHERE  lr.which_group_id = 119287
ORDER  BY lr.submitted_on DESC
LIMIT  25;
```

I don't see any problems with the query per se.

#### Index corruption?

(I don't think so.)

> Could this be some kind of an indexing issue?

If you suspect corruption, run `REINDEX`. [The manual suggests:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

> If you suspect corruption of an index on a user table, you can simply
>   rebuild that index, or all indexes on the table, using `REINDEX INDEX`
>   or `REINDEX TABLE`.

In case of concurrent access: locking differs from dropping and recreating indexes from scratch in several aspects. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

> `REINDEX` is similar to a drop and recreate of the index in that the
>   index contents are rebuilt from scratch. However, the locking
>   considerations are rather different. `REINDEX` locks out writes but not
>   reads of the index's parent table. It also takes an exclusive lock on
>   the specific index being processed, which will block reads that
>   attempt to use that index. In contrast, `DROP INDEX` momentarily takes
>   an exclusive lock on the parent table, blocking both writes and reads.
>   The subsequent `CREATE INDEX` locks out writes but not reads; since the
>   index is not there, no read will attempt to use it, meaning that there
>   will be no blocking but reads might be forced into expensive
>   sequential scans.

If that's still a problem for concurrent operations, consider [`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html#sql-createindex-concurrently) to create new duplicate indexes and then drop the old ones in a separate transaction.

#### Table statistics

***However***, it very much looks like table statistics are the actual problem. Quote from your query plan:

```
Index Scan Backward using links_reply_submitted_on on links_reply
(cost=0.44..1,664,030.07 rows=2,001 width=50)
(actual time=522.811..716.414 rows=25 loops=1)
    Filter: (which_group_id = 119287)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 1721320
```

Bold emphasis mine. Looks like Postgres bases this query plan on misleading statistics. It expects many more hits and probably also underestimates the selectivity of the predicate `which_group_id = 119287`. Ends up filtering 1.7M rows. This *reeks* of inaccurate table statistics. And there is a likely explanation, too:

When upgrading major versions [**`pg_upgrade`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) does not copy existing statistics over to the new version of the DB. It is recommended to run `VACUUM ANALYZE` or at least `ANALYZE` after `pg_upgrade`. The tool even prompts to remind you. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html)

> Because optimizer statistics are not transferred by `pg_upgrade`, you
>   will be instructed to run a command to regenerate that information at
>   the end of the upgrade. You might need to set connection parameters to
>   match your new cluster.

If you don't, tables go without current statistics until autovacuum is triggered by enough writes to the table (or some other utility command like `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE` update some statistics on the fly).

The same is true for any dump / restore cycle (with `pg_dump` & `pg_restore` in your case). Table statistics are not included in the dump.

Your table is very big `(~25M rows)`. Default setting for autovacuum define the threshold as percentage of the row_count plus fixed offset. Sometimes this does not work well for big tables, it will take quite some time until the next auto-analyze.

Run manual `ANALYZE` on the table or on the whole DB.

Related:

- [Tiny table causes extreme performance degradation, fixed by forced VACUUM. Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181960/tiny-table-causes-extreme-performance-degradation-fixed-by-forced-vacuum-why/183283#183283)
- [Index usage on a temporary table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153404/index-usage-on-a-temporary-table/153439#153439)

#### Better index

> ... indexing issue, specifically with the `links_reply_submitted_on` index?

Yes, that, too. The index `"links_reply_submitted_on" btree (submitted_on)` is not optimized for the pattern in your query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   links_reply            lr
JOIN   ...
WHERE  lr.which_group_id = 119287
ORDER  BY lr.submitted_on DESC
LIMIT  25
```

Like we have seen in the query plan above, Postgres uses an index scan, reading the index from the bottom and filters non-matches. This approach can be reasonably fast if all (few!) selected `which_group_id` have 25 rows in the recent past. But it won't work so well for an uneven distribution of rows or many distinct values for `which_group_id`.

This multicolumn index is a better fit:

```
links_reply__which_group_id__submitted_on btree (which_group_id, submitted_on DESC)
```

Now, Postgres can just pick the top 25 rows for the selected `which_group_id`, irregardless of data distribution.

Related:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

#### More explanation

Regarding your observation:

> Lastly, I've also noticed (from user experience) that for all group
>   objects created till last week, the query still performs fast. But all
>   new objects being created now are producing slow log.

Why? New objects may not yet *have* 25 entries, so Postgres has to keep scanning the entire big index in the hope to find more. While this is extremely expensive with your old index and query plan, the same is very cheap with the new index (and updated table statistics).

Also, with accurate table statistics, Postgres would most probably have used your other index `"links_reply_which_group_id" btree (which_group_id)` to grab the few existing rows quickly (and sort if there are more than 25). But my new index offers a more reliable query plan in any case.

#### Minor things

There are various other (minor) things you could do, like optimizing table layout or tuning autovacuum settings, but this answer is long enough already. Related:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

And you later commented:

> Also removed extraneous fields ...

It certainly helps to only retrieve columns you actually need. Do that, in addition. But it's not the main issue here.

Comment: Quick followup question: I read in the docs that `ANALYZE` imposes a read lock on the target table. Does that specifically refer to `ACCESS SHARE` lock (like a `SELECT` query)? Just want to confirm whether I can run `ANALYZE` without taking my production DB offline.

Comment: @HassanBaig: The actual lock level is [`SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) which does not conflict with DML commands.

Comment: A question: I realized I sanitized information that might (or might not) be critical to your guidance. In my particular case, I did not use `pg_upgrade` to upgrade from `9.3` to `9.6`. Instead: I created `pg_dump` in 9.3, set up a fresh machine, installed 9.6 there and directly used `pg_restore` to restore the 9.3 dump into 9.6. Does this change anything vis-a-vis your guidance?

Comment: @HassanBaig: Coincidentally, I already added info on that to my answer. The same advice applies.

Comment: You're right, I now see what you meant by `The same is true for any dump / restore cycle...`

Comment: So far, here's the status: I've run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the problematic table. I've also run `ANALYZE` on the whole DB. Unfortunately, the query is still filling up the slow log. I'm next going to go with the better index you've suggested (provisioned a maintenance window for it). I'll report the results after that.

Comment: If you use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` (like I also mentioned above) it won't conflict with concurrent read / write on the table and you can do it right away.