# Poor query performance over timestamp range by week in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: optimization, postgresql-9.3, performance, timestamp, postgresql-performance

I have a slow query that generates a report of account activity per week over the past year. The table currently has nearly 5 million rows and this query currently takes 8 seconds to execute. The (current) bottleneck is the sequential scan over the timestamp range.

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;

 GroupAggregate  (cost=450475.76..513465.44 rows=2290534 width=12) (actual time=7524.474..8003.291 rows=52 loops=1)
   Group Key: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date)
   ->  Sort  (cost=450475.76..456202.09 rows=2290534 width=12) (actual time=7519.053..7691.924 rows=2314164 loops=1)
         Sort Key: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date)
         Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 40704kB
         ->  Seq Scan on account_history  (cost=0.00..169364.81 rows=2290534 width=12) (actual time=1470.438..6222.076 rows=2314164 loops=1)
               Filter: ((event_time <= now()) AND (event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2591679
 Planning time: 0.126 ms
 Execution time: 8011.160 ms
```

The table:

```
account=> \d account_history
                    Table "public.account_history"
   Column    |            Type             |         Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------
 account     | integer                     | not null
 event_code  | text                        | not null
 event_time  | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 description | text                        | not null default ''::text
Indexes:
    "account_history_idx" btree (account, event_time DESC)
    "account_id_idx" btree (account, event_code, event_time)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "account_fk" FOREIGN KEY (account) REFERENCES account(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "event_code_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_code) REFERENCES domain_account_event(code) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

When I originally created this table, I added the timestamp column as part of a btree index, but I figured that the sequential scan was due to the (then) small number of rows in the table (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203755/why-does-postgresql-perform-sequential-scan-on-indexed-column)).

However, now the table has grown into the millions, I've noticed a performance issue with the query, and discovered that the index is not being used in the query.

I tried adding an ordered index as recommended [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns), but that is clearly not being used in the execution plan either.

Is there a better way to index this table, or is there something inherent in my query that is bypassing both of these indices?

---

Update: When I add an index over *only* the timestamp, that index is used. However, it only reduced the execution time by 25%:

```
account=> CREATE INDEX account_history_time_idx ON account_history (event_time DESC);

account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;

 GroupAggregate  (cost=391870.30..454870.16 rows=2290904 width=12) (actual time=5481.930..6104.838 rows=52 loops=1)
   Output: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date), count(DISTINCT account)
   Group Key: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date)
   ->  Sort  (cost=391870.30..397597.56 rows=2290904 width=12) (actual time=5474.181..5771.903 rows=2314038 loops=1)
         Output: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date), account
         Sort Key: ((to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date)
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 40688kB
         ->  Index Scan using account_history_time_idx on public.account_history  (cost=0.44..110710.59 rows=2290904 width=12) (actual time=0.108..4352.143 rows=2314038 loops=1)
               Output: (to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date, account
               Index Cond: ((account_history.event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)) AND (account_history.event_time <= now()))
 Planning time: 0.204 ms
 Execution time: 6112.832 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/PSfU

I also tried `VACUUM FULL` as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98995/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-one-column?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it made no difference in the execution time.

---

Here are execution plans for some simpler queries over the same table:

Simply counting the rows takes 0.5 seconds:

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_history;

 Aggregate  (cost=97401.04..97401.05 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=551.179..551.179 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Seq Scan on public.account_history  (cost=0.00..85136.43 rows=4905843 width=0) (actual time=0.039..344.675 rows=4905843 loops=1)
         Output: account, event_code, event_time, description
 Planning time: 0.075 ms
 Execution time: 551.209 ms
```

And using the same time range clause takes less than one second:

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now();

 Aggregate  (cost=93527.57..93527.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=997.436..997.436 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Index Only Scan using account_history_time_idx on public.account_history  (cost=0.44..87800.45 rows=2290849 width=0) (actual time=0.100..897.776 rows=2313987 loops=1)
         Output: event_time
         Index Cond: ((account_history.event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)) AND (account_history.event_time <= now()))
         Heap Fetches: 2313987
 Planning time: 0.239 ms
 Execution time: 997.473 ms
```

---

Based on the comments, I tried a simplified form of the query:

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT date_trunc('week', event_time) AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history
WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;

 GroupAggregate  (cost=374676.22..420493.00 rows=2290839 width=12) (actual time=2475.556..3078.191 rows=52 loops=1)
   Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), count(DISTINCT account)
   Group Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
   ->  Sort  (cost=374676.22..380403.32 rows=2290839 width=12) (actual time=2468.654..2763.739 rows=2313977 loops=1)
         Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), account
         Sort Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 49720kB
         ->  Index Scan using account_history_time_idx on public.account_history  (cost=0.44..93527.35 rows=2290839 width=12) (actual time=0.094..1537.488 rows=2313977 loops=1)
               Output: date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), account
               Index Cond: ((account_history.event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)) AND (account_history.event_time <= now()))
 Planning time: 0.220 ms
 Execution time: 3086.828 ms
(12 rows)

account=> SELECT date_trunc('week', current_date) AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWE
EN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
          date          | count
------------------------+-------
 2017-10-23 00:00:00-04 |   132
(1 row)
```

Indeed, that cut the execution time in half, but unfortunately does not give the desired results, as in:

```
account=> SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
    date    | count
------------+-------
 2016-10-31 |    14
...
 2017-10-23 |   584
(52 rows)
```

If I can find a cheaper way to aggregate these records by week, that will go a long way toward solving this problem.

---

I am open to any suggestions on improving the performance of the weekly query with the `GROUP BY` clause, including altering the table.

I created a materialized view as a test, but of course refreshing it takes exactly the same amount of time as the original query, so unless I only refresh it a few times per day, it doesn't really help, at the cost of adding complexity:

```
account=> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW account_activity_weekly AS SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
SELECT 52
```

---

Based on an additional comment, I have revised my query as follows, which cut the execution time in half and does deliver the expected result set:

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date_trunc('week', event_time) ORDER BY date;

 Sort  (cost=724523.11..730249.97 rows=2290745 width=12) (actual time=3188.495..3188.496 rows=52 loops=1)
   Output: ((to_timestamp(to_char((date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date), (count(DISTINCT account)), (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time))
   Sort Key: ((to_timestamp(to_char((date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time)), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date)
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=374662.50..443384.85 rows=2290745 width=12) (actual time=2573.694..3188.451 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: (to_timestamp(to_char((date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), 'IYYY-IW'::text), 'IYYY-IW'::text))::date, count(DISTINCT account), (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time))
         Group Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
         ->  Sort  (cost=374662.50..380389.36 rows=2290745 width=12) (actual time=2566.086..2859.590 rows=2313889 loops=1)
               Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), event_time, account
               Sort Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 67816kB
               ->  Index Scan using account_history_time_idx on public.account_history  (cost=0.44..93524.23 rows=2290745 width=12) (actual time=0.090..1503.985 rows=2313889 loops=1)
                     Output: date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), event_time, account
                     Index Cond: ((account_history.event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)) AND (account_history.event_time <= now()))
 Planning time: 0.205 ms
 Execution time: 3198.125 ms
(16 rows)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `to_timestamp(to_char(date_trunc('week', event_time), 'IYYY-IW'), 'IYYY-IW')::date` can be simplified to `date_trunc('week', current_date)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I appreciate the suggestion, but that aggregates at the wrong granularity, returning only a single row in the result set when I expect exactly 52 rows (one year by week). Results: `2017-10-23 00:00:00-04 | 132 (1 row)` vs. `2016-10-31 | 14 ... 2017-10-23 | 584 (52 rows)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, you might be on to something there. The simpler form of the `date_trunc` does cut the query time in half. However, it doesn't give me the result set I'm looking for.

Comment: Try using @a_horse_with_no_name's formula in GROUP BY, leavibg the SELECT as it is: `group by date_trunc('week', event_time)`

Comment: And I'm not sure, maybe an index on `(event_time, account)` would help, too. How many distinct account values are there in the whole table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Your first suggestion worked, and my mind is blown. Why did that work? Also, I already have an ordered index on those columns: `account_history_idx" btree (account, event_time DESC)`. There are 4,905,843 rows in the table, of which 2,313,993 rows are used to produce the results.

Comment: I suggested the index with the opposite order. The one you have might be used - but not for this query. Perhaps if it was rewritten. The row number info is good but I asked how many distinct accounts there are.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There are 773 distinct accounts. I tried that index in the opposite order and the execution plan resorted to a sequential scan again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67596/discussion-between-ypercube-and-vallismortis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to those who contributed in the comments, I have reduced the query time from ~8000 ms to ~1650 ms by:

- Adding an index on the timestamp column only (~2000 ms improvement).
- Removing the extra timestamp-to-char-to-timestamp conversion (or adding `date_trunc('week', event_time)` to the `GROUP BY` clause) (~3000 ms improvement).

For reference, the current table structure and execution plan are below.

I did play around with the other variations of indexing over multiple columns, but none of those indices were used by the execution plan.

In addition, I took the advice of another comment and took the following steps (followed by VACUUM and REINDEX):

- Dropped the constraints from the description column and set all empty strings to NULL
- Converted the timestamp column from `WITHOUT TIME ZONE` to `WITH TIME ZONE`
- Increased the work_mem to 100MB (via `postgresql.conf`).

---

```
ALTER TABLE account_history ALTER event_time TYPE timestamptz USING event_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
ALTER TABLE account_history ALTER COLUMN description DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE account_history ALTER COLUMN description DROP DEFAULT;
UPDATE account_history SET description=NULL WHERE description='';
VACUUM FULL;
REINDEX TABLE account_history;

account=> show work_mem;
 work_mem
----------
 100MB
```

---

These additional changes shaved another 400ms from the execution time and also cut down the planning time. One thing to note is that the sort method has changed from "external sort" to "external merge". Since the 'Disk' was still being used for the sort, I increased the work_mem to 200MB, which resulted in the quicksort (memory) method being used (176MB). This dropped a full second off the execution time (although this is really too high to be used on our server instances).

The updated table and execution plan are below.

---

```
account=> \d account_history
                 Table "public.account_history"
   Column    |           Type           |       Modifiers
-------------+--------------------------+------------------------
 account     | integer                  | not null
 event_code  | text                     | not null
 event_time  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 description | text                     |
Indexes:
    "account_history_account_idx" btree (account)
    "account_history_account_time_idx" btree (event_time DESC, account)
    "account_history_time_idx" btree (event_time DESC)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "account_fk" FOREIGN KEY (account) REFERENCES account(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "event_code_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_code) REFERENCES domain_account_event(code) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

---

```
account=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT date_trunc('week', event_time) AS date, count(DISTINCT account) FROM account_history WHERE event_time BETWEEN now() - interval '51 weeks' AND now() GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;

 GroupAggregate  (cost=334034.60..380541.52 rows=2325346 width=12) (actual time=1307.742..1685.676 rows=52 loops=1)
   Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), count(DISTINCT account)
   Group Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
   ->  Sort  (cost=334034.60..339847.97 rows=2325346 width=12) (actual time=1303.565..1361.540 rows=2312418 loops=1)
         Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, event_time)), account
         Sort Key: (date_trunc('week'::text, account_history.event_time))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 176662kB
         ->  Index Only Scan using account_history_account_time_idx on public.account_history  (cost=0.44..88140.73 rows=2325346 width=12) (actual time=0.028..980.822 rows=2312418 loops=1)
               Output: date_trunc('week'::text, event_time), account
               Index Cond: ((account_history.event_time >= (now() - '357 days'::interval)) AND (account_history.event_time <= now()))
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.153 ms
 Execution time: 1697.824 ms
```

---

I am very happy with the improvements thus far, but I welcome any other contributions to improving the performance of this query, since this is still the slowest query I have in one of my views.

Comment: Why are you still doing `to_char`? Get rid of `to_timestamp(to_char())` and just use `date_trunc()`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `timestamp without time zone` you should be using `timestamp with time zone`. You should also permit `description` to be null and set `''` to `null`. You should cluster on `event_time`. also what is `work_mem`. Run `show work_mem;`.

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL `work_mem` is 1MB. My production and test databases are in different time zones, but everything is set to UTC. I recall some issue with JDBC and PostgreSQL not agreeing on timezone conversions, (i.e. `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Timestamp`). That said, I will give it another shot and will report back.

Comment: So if they're in different time zones, you would want them to pull out the time stamps in the timezones specified in the clients `TIME ZONE`. That's what `with time zone` does. As for 1 MB work_mem that's way too low. Raise that to 100 MB: `ALTER SYSTEM SET work_mem = 100mb; SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL I made all of the changes you recommended, which yielded another 400 ms improvement, although I'm uncertain which changes were responsible. Even with 100MB work_mem, I'm still seeing 'Disk' in the execution plan.

Comment: try restarting the service and checking to see if work_mem is still 100mb. Did you cluster on date time?

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL Yes, I needed 176MB of work_mem to get the execution plan to switch to a memory-based quicksort. I tried clustering on each index, but it actually had a negative effect on performance - added ~200ms.

Comment: That's all the easy options though. Consider dropping account_history_time_idx because you're not using it. If you need something substantially faster than 1697.824 you'll have to materialize it. Such as caching the the dates and unique customers for every day, and then joining from the cache to get the last completed day and then finishing up with the query from there.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a quick date between query issue. I converted dates to Unix time (UTC) (I only needed “second” accurancy but you could go finer if you need to)
Then create a method to convert your dates to a bigint/long (include your Timezone conversion here). Then run your query and just search between the 2 integers. May sound a bit wild but works like a dream.

Comment: I don't think that converting a timestamp to an epoch and comparing those bigints really improved things. I would rather guess that while you were doing that, you probably changed the way the query works or you created additional indexes that weren't there to begin with. An index on a timestamp column will be just as efficient as an index on a bigint column. And you don't really need to _create_ a function to convert between unix epoch and a proper timestamp - Postgres already provides functions for that

Comment: I managed to get a 55x speedup on a query by converting part of a where clause from "ts between timestamp <iso stamp1> and <iso stamp2>" to "extract(epoch from ts) between <unix int1> and <unix int2>. The "ts" column in this case is a timestamp that is not timezone aware. This seems kinda insane.